# How to send a file, created inside a slot, from one independent slot to another?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have two actions on my toolbar: saveaction, and startaction

```
   saveaction is connected to save() slot
   startaction is connected to optimize() slot
```

A file is created inside optimize(). And I want to save file inside save().

Since there are called when signals are triggered, they (slots) should be independent.
So I have,

```
void Mainwidnow::optimize()
{
    //here a file is created

    // and I want to send this file to save()
}
```

When I push savebutton on toolbar (saveaction).

```
void Mainwindow::save()
{
    //here I want actually get file and save
    get = thefile
    saveit();
}
```

I think I can not call save() inside optimize(), because it is called every time optimize() is called, but what I want is it should called whenever saveaction is triggered.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you call this->save() in the optimize()?

Comment: Because There are connected into two different actions. I want to save file call save() whenever I want to save, not every time I start optimize().

Answer (score 0):

Slots are normal methods, so the simplest is just to call it :

```
void Mainwidnow::optimize()
{
    //here a file is created

    // and I want to send this file to save()
    save();
}
```

If you want something more exotic, you could connect a signal to the `save()` slot, and emit the signal.

---

The only thing to add to your comment is to extract common functionality into a class (or a function), and call it when you need it.

Your requirements should be clear enough to say what should when happen. Nobody on SO can tell you how your application should behave.

Comment: But the save() will be called always when optimize() called in this case, which I do not want. Because the slots are connected to two different signals. I want to save whenever save action is triggered, not whenever optimize. Any idea, how I can reach the goal?

Comment: Omg. Create a normal algorithm first. Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have edited my question. Is it clear now what I want?

Comment: then can you please tell what you do not understand?

Comment: @user3185491 post a real example, with what you need. What you posted is not even pseudo code